# Writing a client contract for Web development?

Tags: web-development, freelancing, html, css

I am a small time web dev freelancer during my time off at university and I have some horror stories when it comes to designing sites for people (not that the sites are bad - just the clients DO NOT KNOW WHAT THEY WANT) this *really* grinds my gears.

To set the context this is what I want to avoid:

> I had a client last year that I built
>   a site for
>   *ANON*.
>   We agreed upon a price (£200 - I am a
>   student so their mentality is "Oh you
>   are a student that makes you cheap
>   right?") I had the site done to the
>   original specification within about 3
>   days (nothing was ever written down be
>   it original specification costs etc it
>   was all done over phone/Skype) The
>   client *then* decided that his
>   original idea wasn't that good looking
>   in practise so I was told to scrap it
>   and start again, fine, Im'm a
>   professional I can take that.
>
> I then redid the site to the new spec
>   that he gave me, took another 3-4 days
>   and the same thing again, don't like
>   it, start again. By this time I'm
>   getting rather annoyed with the lack
>   of constructive criticism, So I redo
>   the site to basically how it is now
>   (see URL above) he says "yeah looks
>   okay ship it" so it gets put on the
>   web THEN he decides "Oh by the way I
>   want and e-commerce solution AND a
>   members only section or you aren't
>   getting paid anything." being in the
>   position I was in I couldn't very well
>   just say no due to the 12 or so days
>   of my life he had waisted so I
>   proceeded to add the e-commerce and
>   members only sections, this then led
>   to a **plethora** of other changes.
>
> For example there is a page with a variety of
>   "packages" the user can choose from, I
>   had these done in *glorious* CSS3 I
>   mean it looked amazing, really chuffed
>   with my work I put it online and
>   linked him to it... "It's crap get rid
>   of it do it in photoshop and put
>   .jpg's up instead". Baffled as to how
>   it could look "crap" I asked what
>   browser he was using... "IE6", I could
>   have killed him, but restrained myself
>   and told him to upgrade to Chrome or
>   FF3.6, So he upgrades to FF, "Wow that
>   looks great!... But still redo it in
>   photoshop so people with IE6 will see
>   it fine" I tried to tell him that the
>   site demographics showed he was the
>   ONLY one using IE6 but he wasn't
>   having any of it, so I spend a while
>   doing it in PS put them up, all was
>   fine.
>
> *Then*, he says "oh by the way I want to change the package prices" I say
>   "well if you had left them in CSS3 and
>   HTML you could have done it yourself",
>   He didn't want to hear it and made me
>   redo the jpg's - This occurs **every
>   time** he has a new package that needs
>   put up as you would imagine this gets
>   very annoying after a while and I was
>   beginning to get fed up, but he
>   decided that with how it was done now
>   looked great and kept him happy, I
>   then asked about payment "Oh I only
>   have £50 that I can give you but I can
>   give you 2x 12 week training
>   packages". I think okay, I'll make the
>   best of a bad situation and take it,
>   so I agree, I get £50 for 2-3weeks
>   work and 1x12 week training package, I
>   finish that then ask about the other
>   one "Oh that was only if I could
>   afford to give it to you, right now I
>   can't so you'll have to pay £120 for
>   that.". Not only that but he keeps
>   pestering me to do little remedial
>   changes on the site that I taught him
>   how to use, but he doesn't want to
>   know, so not only am I not getting
>   paid for any changes I make for him he
>   threatens me that if I don't change
>   them he's going to spread bad rep about me to any of his clients and everyone he knows.

As you can imagine this got me very edgy about clients and I would now like to develop a contract that:

- No compromises are made for IE6.
- 25% up front 25% half-way and 50% upon completion.
- I have a *minimum* standard that I will work to so jobs under £500 are not viable.
- Remedial and quarterly changes are payable on a per-hour rate.
- I can reserve the right to take down any site if the 50% upon completion is not paid within 30 days.
- There are no "cash-substitutes" - no cash - no site.

If anyone could suggest what to add above as clauses in my contract and if the above are suitable, as in would they scare clients off?

Any suggestions on any part of the contract would be appreciated as well as where to get them written up.

Thanks all!

Comment: Voting to migrate on programmers.SE

Comment: We totally need a contractual-law.SE site... =/

Comment: You're a student, so you may not be able to afford this generic advice, but get a lawyer to check it over - the last thing you want is if somehow you end up in court, the contract being thrown out on a technicality.

Comment: I would have immediately stopped working for him (and seriously considered the option of taking down the site he already had online) as soon as he hinted at not paying you..  you would have lost at worst 7-8 days instead of 'taking it in the rear entry'..

Comment: About IE: a HUGE percentage of users is still hanging with it so, as a designer working in the field for 7 years now, I strongly advise you to develop **always** with backward compatibility in mind, even if it is a big loss of time (and a real pain in the a**).

Comment: @Lucius Not IE6? ie6countdown.com - from M$ themselves

Comment: Well, it may depend on the target of the website you're going to develop, but figures from 10% to 34% on a total population of over 3 billion people still make the slice of pie still quite interesting to me..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The clauses you mention sound fairly reasonable to me.

Just make sure the tone of the contract is calm and professional; don't let your edginess show through. Remember that it's not new clients' fault that you've had negative experiences in the past.

The last point (about cash substitutes) is so obvious that it doesn't need to be explicitly mentioned IMO. Nobody can make you accept their services instead of a cash payment.

Comment: Point taken, I have non anon'd the OP - On the front of where to get a contract written up, any advice? Would you add any clauses to the contract?

Comment: @Myles tips on how to write a good contract will probably vary very much from jurisdiction to jurisdiction. An hour of a competent lawyer's time might be a worthwhile investment. Alternatively, maybe check with professional associations for contract templates - but there are also likely to be online resources that help with this. It's just important that they're specific to your country.

Comment: @Myles additionally, maybe add payment deadlines customary to your country (here in Germany, it's usually 8 working days). Always have the client sign very detailed agreements of what is to be done prior to starting work. If possible, even including screen shots. Any additional changes you can then bill extra. Always see that you put technical things in layman's terms so a judge can understand them.

Comment: Right you are, I must check up on UK/NI contractual law, I may be able to get one of my parents to have their lawyer get a quick look over it for a few £ :) - I'll check it out online and try and make it as short as possible (I'll keep it professional too some clients like the above REALLY rile me up) good idea with the screen shots too, Ill defiantly do that too!

Answer (score 6):

First off, if there is no contract and he isn't paying you, then do not do the work!  Second, if he threatens to 'slander' you then you can go after him.  May not be worth it in this case if he has no money, so chances are he won't have much credibility either.

For deliverables I would recommend not giving specific dates.  ie. Designs will be delivered on March 12th.  If the client doesn't give you approval to start until the 11th then you could be in a bind.

Instead say "Designs will be delivered within 10 days of receiving project approval."
Another example "The working site will be ready for review 20 days after the final design has been approved."

This also helps in case one area takes longer and overlaps when something else was suppose to be worked on.

Also, don't make your contracts pages upon pages.  Here's some helpful [resources](http://webdesign.about.com/od/contracts/Contracts.-qQI.htm) on [contracts](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/06/freelance-contracts-dos-and-donts/).

Comment: Thank you very good advice on the binding dates, I had never thought of that, I'll take a look at those resources too.

Answer (score 4):

I don't want to be rude but: **You don't need a contract, you need guts** to talk to your client. How do you pass from a 200 bucks site to an e-commerce solution? And why you accepted that weird payment or the fact that he threats you? quick advice: at the first sign of no paying, stop working.

Don't find a lawyer, just find better clients, there's a lot of good people out there.

Comment: I almost completely agree.  He needs guts first and foremost, but he also needs a contract.  A lack of guts caused this problem, but guts alone won't protect you from all of the things a contract will.

Comment: I agree, Just need to man up and tell him how it is... But a contract will also help me to find clients who won't mess with me.

Comment: @Myles yup! but also remember that a contract can put you in trouble if you land on another bad client and, for any reason, you don't respect a clause (delays are common). The contract is there to protect you AND PROTECT THEM. So, write a contract but also find nice people to work for. After all that's the cool part of be a freelance, you can choose your clients  :)